# get exit status from system() call

Tags: vimscript, external-command, shell

Calling the function `system("<command>")` or `systemlist("<command>")` retrieves the stdout output from a shell call to `<command>`. How can I retrieve the exit status of that command?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
let output =  system_call_with_exit_status("my_shell_command")
let stdout = output[0]
let exit_status = output[1]
if (exit_status != 0)
    echo output
endif
```

The intention is to print the output from `my_shell_command` only if the command gives a non-zero exit status.

Comment: `:h v:shell_error`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks, that works.

Comment: @Jasha consider self-answering if youve got it figured out now

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ok, will do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mentioned in the comments above, the `v:shell_error` variable gives the result of the last shell command. So the exit status can be tested as follows:

```
let output = system("my_shell_command")
if v:shell_error != 0
    echo output
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Lua, the following utility function also helps:

```lua
function shell_error()
  return vim.v.shell_error ~= 0
end
```